# Remove extra space from top of CSS columns in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/5tehhb0n/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
    background-color: blue;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.item {
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

In Chrome, this results in the first item in the second column having a space above it, caused by the margin of the last item in the first column:

[image: Example]

Setting `display: inline-block` on each `.item` solves the issue but I need to maintain margin-collapsing, which does not work with `inline-block`.

Is there some way to avoid the extra space and still keep `display: block` on each `.item`?

Comment: remove the margin-bottom: 50px;

Answer (score 2):

> **Note:** your example works perfectly in IE 11 and the new Edge browser, with no gap present. I'm not sure which browser has the correct behaviour, but the gap is only present in Chrome and Firefox. The workaround I present below is broken in IE 11 but works fine in Edge.

### A slightly odd workaround

The bottom margin is leaking through to the second column. Luckily, a bottom border does not have the same behaviour, so we can:

- Remove the margin and re-create it with a transparent border:

  ```
  .item {
     border-bottom: solid 50px transparent;
  }
  ```
- Use a [pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/::before) to create the background instead as it will not stretch underneath the border (the transparent border would show the items background). The pseudo-element can be layered underneath the items contents with `z-index: -1`:

  ```
  .item:before {
     content: '';
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     right: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     left: 0;
     background: red;
     z-index: -1;
  }
  ```
- Place the background of `.wrapper` behind the items pseudo-element with `z-index: -1`. It must also have `position: relative` for the z-index to work:

  ```
  .wrapper {
      position: relative;
      z-index: -1;
  }
  ```

#### Full Example

```css
.wrapper {
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
.item {
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  border-bottom: solid 50px transparent;
  position: relative;
}
.item:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: red;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></div>  
</div>
```